# grep strings from all files in directory - Not exact match

Tags: bash, grep

I want to be able to look through all files in directory and search for multiple strings , however, I want to search for the first 2 letters of a string and then auto complete the rest of the string, then return the string and remove any duplicates.

```
So far I have grep -0 'WQ[^$]' *
```

It returns the first 2 letters and first number off the string, however, it does not return full string. I am looking to search by the first 2 letters and find all matches but return the full value of the string?

Comment: I think you're looking for `grep -o 'WQ.*' *`, which will match each line that contains `WQ` and display from that `WQ` up to the end of the line. If you want to match up to the end of the file rather than the line, `grep -zo 'WQ.*' *` ought to do it

Comment: You want to return everything to the end of the line?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to search and find all strings in Al files that start with WQ but untill end of that value / line.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print if(/\bWQ.*/)' *
```